# Select from non-scalar VBA function

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I can use scalar VBA functions in SQL query like this

```
SELECT vba_concat(name, surname) FROM persons
```

Also I can use non-scalar SQL functions in SQL query like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION names() RETURNS TABLE(name VARCHAR(20)) AS '
    SELECT name FROM persons;
' LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM names();
```

But how can I use non-scalar **VBA** functions in SQL query like this `SELECT * FROM vba_ids()` where `vba_ids()` defined as `Public Function vba_ids() As ADODB.Recordset`.

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM (select [name] from persons) as vba_ids`?

Comment: @Remou this function is just an example. In really I have more complex vba function that I want to use in query.

Comment: You would need to provide a more complex example. You cannot use the same methods you would in SQL Server.

Comment: @Remou so the only type of vba functions that can be used in sql queries is scalar fuctions?

Comment: Access consists of two parts, the coding side and the database side. Often enough the database is Jet/ACE but it can be most other databases. When you reference VBA, you are passing data from the RAD tool to the database, so you cannot pass a recordset as such.

Comment: @Remou it's all I want to know, thanks! Post it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Access consists of two parts, the coding side and the database side. Often enough the database is Jet/ACE but it can be most other databases. When you reference VBA, you are passing data from the RAD tool to the database, so you cannot pass a recordset as such.